# I want script detect more than one word using tampermonkey please

Tags: html, tampermonkey

I have this tampermonkey script that detect a word and refresh the webpage if it didn't find it, it works great and all but I want it to detect MULTIPLE WORDS not just one and if it don't find any of the words it refresh the page, but if it found only one it should notify me. here is the script

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Page loaded.");
    var LookFor = "cheese";

    var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
    var hasText = content.indexOf(LookFor) !== -1;
    if(hasText) {
        console.log("Text found! Alerting.");
        alert("Found: " + LookFor);
    } else {
        console.log("Text not found - reloading.");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We do not write scripts here.

Comment: oh sorry I saw some posts here where people share scripts, can you tell me where to ask my question ? is there a particular place ?

Comment: Ignore the haters - many of us *do* assist when a beginner coder is stuck. Others (see above) only help advanced coders. Ignore their snide comments and keep using StackOverflow. Someone will help.

Comment: thanks for the mood boosting comment, if I face any issue I will ask about it here, thank you :)

Comment: @cssyphus 100% agree with you, I also enjoy helping beginners, there is some elitism on SO.  Haza just like cssyphus said, "...just ignore the haters..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply add an array of what to match, and then loop

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("Page loaded.");
    var findUs = ["cheese", "mushroom"];
    var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
    var hasText = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < findUs.length; i++) {
        if (content.indexOf(findUs[i]) !== -1) {
            hasText = true;
            break; // Exit the loop early if any match is found
        }
    }
    if (hasText) {
        console.log("Text found! Alerting.");
        alert("Found one of these: " + findUs.join(', '));
        // TODO: MAKE AN API CALL HERE TO NOTIFY YOU
    } else {
        console.log("Text not found - reloading.");
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: omg Thank You !!! you are the best human that exist in my eyes right now thanks a lot